# identical model fit results when using anova?

Tags: r

I am comparing two models one of them uses 2-level analysis, while the other uses 3-level analysis and I am getting identical results for both models when using anova: using R, lme4

```
anova(finalModel, finalmodelML)
Data: mydata
Models:
finalModel: healthState ~ days + gender + age + diabetes + stroke + cardiacRehab + 
finalModel:     drugAdherence + drugCompliance + (days | patientNum)
finalmodelML: healthState ~ days + gender + age + diabetes + stroke + cardiacRehab + 
finalmodelML:     drugAdherence + drugCompliance + (days | hospital:patientNum)
             Df     AIC   BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
finalModel   14 -7259.4 -7167 3643.7  -7287.4                        
finalmodelML 14 -7259.4 -7167 3643.7  -7287.4     0      0          1
```

Could there be something wrong with my analysis?

Comment: Could there be something wrong with my R file?? is it possible to get a value of 1 for pr(>chisq)

Comment: am I just being too cautious...could this be a good result of anova??

Comment: it looks like your second model is ignoring 'hospital'. If that's true I'd guess that finalModel and finalmodelNL are the same, hence the identical fits. Without more information on the data it's hard to say more.

Comment: I think this really belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com (CrossValidated). The answer is that `patientNum` is unique, so `hospital:patientNum` actually has the same information.  You could use `hospital/patientNum` (patient nested within hospital).

Answer (score 2):

Grouping your random effect by patientNum will be the same as grouping by hospital:patientNum because patientNum is unique.

If you get `table(patientNum)` and `table(interaction(hospital, patientNum))` then you should notice that all of the cells are the same size.